# RPi not re-connecting to network after MacBook connects to Network

Tags: wifi, connection

First, I have checked other forums/questions about this. Tried different solutions like using the wpa_supplicant file, writing a script that restarts/attemps to reconnect the Pi after dropping its connection, tried changing wpa-roam for wpa-conf... and I don't know what else.

The issue, as the title says, is that my Pi will drop the Wi-Fi connection every time my flatmate uses his MacBook. Normally this happens while I'm at work so I don't know if that's because there's a reboot of the router, which usually occurs when streaming a lot of content. (That is why I tried all the re-connection options I've stumbled upon).

I know it sounds a bit vague or even stupid but it's all I can contribute at the moment.

Any suggestions or ideas to this?

Comment: have you maybe set a static IP that's conflicting with the Mac's?

Comment: I've tried with different IPs, moving from x.x.x.15 to x.x.x.115 in various stages, it would be quite incidental they always conflicted with the mac, wouldn't it? Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

- change your RPi2 MAC
- in your DHCP server conf assign it a lease OUTSIDE of it's dynamical range, i.e. x.x.x.115 when your dynamic range is x.x.x.10-x.x.x.100
- make a static address in your RPi2 `/etc/network/interfaces`

it should work fail-safely

Comment: I always advise people to set a static IP via their router rather than in the PI. This is a lot more portable.

Comment: @Havnar I agree, but in this case we need to avoid the IP-range conflicts and ensure that even in DHCP case it will be avoided(via assigning off-range IP statically by MAC address of RPi2)

Comment: So far looks like it is working, will keep you updated. Thanks very much!

Comment: @Alejandro can you mark it as an answer then?

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin It didn't work actually, last night happened again :/

Comment: @Alejandro - let's continue, then! Make the same hard MAC-based binding for a laptop of your friend? What is your WiFi router? How it's configured? WiFi security=? DHCP configuration?

Comment: @AlexeyVesninWiFi security is WPKA2, The router is the one given by Sky (Sky hub I think is called?) and default DHCP configuration. Will try that same thing tonight, thanks!